# TLSはパケットに送信元IPアドレスが含まれない？

Tags: network, ssl

HTTPSのようなプロトコルでTLSがどう使われているのか検索してると以下のページを見掛けました。
ここにはTLSはパケットに送信元IPアドレスが含まれないという特徴を持つと書かれていました。

[3分で読める最新脆弱性～TLS～アルパカ攻撃 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/reacon4234/items/ffeaca76ada2fb088153)

> TLSは、HTTPS、SMTP、IMAP、POP3、FTP などの複数のアプリケーション層プロトコルを支える暗号プロトコルです。ネットワーク経由の通信を保護し、転送中に認証層を追加し、交換されたデータの整合性を維持することを目的としています。(デフォルトでは)パケットに送信元/送信元IPアドレスが含まれないという特徴を持ちます。

しかし自分の認識だとTLSヘッダに送信元IPアドレスが含まれないだけで、TLSよりも下位層のIPヘッダに送信元IPアドレスが含まれているはずなのでパケットに送信元IPアドレスが含まれていないという点が疑問に感じました。

もしデフォルトではパケットに送信元IPアドレスが含まれないなら、TLSではどのようにして通信を行うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

記事にはいきなり「パケット」が登場していますが、これが何を指す名称なのか全く不明です。少なくともTLSの用語ではありません。ただし、言わんとしていることはわかります。

TLSはあくまで双方向通信されるストリームであり、その伝送方法は規定していません。TCP/IPを使用する必要はなく、伝書鳩でも構いません。
例えば、[Microsoft Windowsに搭載されているSChannel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/secure-channel)はTLS通信をサポートしていますが、こちらはあくまで送信するデータの暗号化と受信したデータの復号のみで、それらデータをどのように送受信するかはアプリケーション側に委ねる設計となっています。

> TLSではどのようにして通信を行うのでしょうか？

もちろんTCP/IPで伝送する際、TLSレコードにTCPヘッダとIPヘッダと付与して送受信します。

Comment: 件の文章はTLSそのものについてTCP/IPを使用しない場合も含め説明している（しかし記事の全体はTCP/IPが前提）ということですね　理解できた気がします。ご回答ありがとうございました。